# Redis data dump from Old Version to new Redis Version

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

We have several Redis version servers like v3, v4 . I'm trying to migrate data from those servers to one Redis v6 version with indexing. I'm new to Redis migration from one version to new Redis version.

How can I do all version data.dump to new Redis v6 data.dump with indexing.

Comment: According to the page at https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/docs/RDB_Version_History.textile (at least up to Redis v5), "Redis dump file is 100% backwards compatible. An older dump file format will always work with a newer version of Redis."  In short - try it.

Comment: I support @AlisterBulman's comment - it should work(tm) as Redis tries hard to maintain backward compatibility

Comment: please send me command for dumping data from old version redis server to new version redis server using indexing redis-cli command